# Getting the Return Value from JDBC MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, return-value

I'm connecting to SQL Server (2005) through Java using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0.

How do I get the return value from a stored procedure? I'm doing something like:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call dbo.mySproc() }");
proc.execute();
```

Should I be using execute()? executeQuery()? executeUpdate()? None of these seem to return a return value by default but I'm not really sure how to get to it.

EDIT 1: To be clear, I know how to call stored procedures. This question is specifically about how to get the RETURN VALUE (as opposed to a Result Set). The Return Value is an integer that is usually generated when you execute a query with no Result Set or if you specifically state something like `RETURN 0` in your SQL.

EDIT 2: executeUpdate() returns an int but this int is not the same as the Return Value. Also, an OUT parameter is not the same as a return value.

Comment: Check the following links [http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/CallProcedure.html](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/CallProcedure.html) [http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30731](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30731)

Comment: I'm looking specifically to get the Return Value, I'm not looking for generic information about calling sprocs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Bozho's 2nd revised answer was close but not quite there. It did lead me to the answer though.

Taking the code example I started with we end up with:

```
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call dbo.mySproc() }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
proc.execute();
int returnValue = proc.getInt(1);
```

The key pieces here are the "? =" in front of the "call" in the `prepareCall` function which sets up a place for the return value and the `registerOutputParameter`. It has to be registered as an Integer, as the return value is always an int (at least in SQL Server, maybe it's different in other DBs). You therefore have to get it using `getInt`. I tested this method and it does work.

Comment: Above, the `Types.INTEGER` is `java.sql.Types.INTEGER`.

Answer (score 2):

```
c.prepareCall("? = ..");
cs.execute();
String returnedValue = cs.getString(1);
```

(or the method of the appropriate type. You can use `getObject` alternatively)

From [an old getting started tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html)

> the getXXX methods in CallableStatement retrieve values from the OUT parameters and/or return value of a stored procedure.

(Btw, the links that were provided by Umesh had this sort of information.)

Comment: That returns an output parameter, which is different from a return value. I think the stored procedure would have to have an output parameter defined in order for this to work.

Comment: no, it isn't in the context of CallableStatement (check my updated answer)

Comment: The prepare call syntax is incorrect (no JDBC escape syntax), the out parameter needs to be registered to be available later, and the link is dead...