# Stored Procedure return codes in Sequel (Ruby ORM)

Tags: ruby, sequel

In MS SQL Server a stored procedure can return an integer value called a [return code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to indicate the execution status of a procedure.

Does Sequel support this?

The value returned from `my_stored_proc.call()` does not match the integer I am returning in SQL. Is there some other way to access this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from Jeremy Evans on the Sequel Talk Google Group was:

> Unfortunately, Sequel's support for stored procedures is fairly limited.  I don't believe it supports return codes or in/out variables.  It's designed similarly to the prepared statement support, where delete/update returns the number of affected rows, and select yields rows.
>
> If Sequel's support doesn't meet your needs, use Database#synchronize to get to the underlying database connection, and operate directly on that using the connection's API (which depends on the driver in use).

"[Getting the Return Value from JDBC MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql)" describes how to do it from a Java perspective.

And, here is a (working) first stab at a Ruby implementation:

```
return_code = @db.synchronize do |conn|
  stmnt = conn.prepareCall('{ ? = call dbo.sp_sequel_test() }')
  stmnt.registerOutParameter(1, java::sql::Types::INTEGER)
  stmnt.execute
  # output parameters have not yet been processed, must call getMoreResults() first.
  stmnt.getMoreResults  
  stmnt.getInt(1)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported from version [4.6](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/release_notes/4.6.0.txt) of Sequel using the `call_mssql_proc` method:

```
DB.call_mssql_sproc(:SequelTest, {:args => ['Input String', :output]})

> {:result => 0, :numrows => 1, :var1 => "1"}
```

The result will be in the `:result` element.

Read "[Stored Procedures in MSSQL](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/mssql_stored_procedures.rdoc)" for more.