# Retrieve the returned value from sql server stored procedure using java

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures

Here is my store procedure that returns a value. I need to call this procedure and get that return value into my java program.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure @advisor de , @adv_xml xml   

AS      


begin        
  declare 
    @psrg_idi idi,
    @adv_cd cd,
    @CurrDate cdt

  set @adv_cd = (select adv_cd from dbo.ADVICE_LK where upper(rtrim(adv_de)) = upper(@advisor))
  set @psrg_idi = 0    
  set @CurrDate = getdate()

    BEGIN TRY     
      exec my_proc_2 @CurrDate,@psrg_idi output

      insert into
          ADVICE
          (psrg_idi,
           adv_cd,
           psra_original_xml)  
      values
        (@psrg_idi,
         @adv_cd,
         @adv_xml)  

      select 
        @psrg_idi as psrg_idi

    END TRY     
    BEGIN CATCH    
       DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);    
       DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;    
       DECLARE @ErrorState INT;     
       SELECT     
         @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),    
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),    
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();    
   -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error    
   -- information about the original error that caused    
   -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.    
   RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.    
     @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.    
     @ErrorState -- State.    
     );    
   return -1    
     END CATCH    

end
```

Here is how I am trying to get this value into my java program returned by the above stored procedure. When I call this procedure from java, all the expected values are stored into database tables. But I am receiving the returned value groupId as '0'.. any idea or help will be highly appreciated.

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{? = call my_procedure (?,?)}");                
int i = 0;
cs.registerOutParameter(++i, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cs.setString(++i, advisor);
cs.setString(++i, adviceXml);

cs.execute();
int groupId = cs.getInt(1);
```

I have already reviewed the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1948518/674476 . I am also trying in the same way, but somehow not able to get returned value

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight, MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution to the problem and it works perfectly fine in my case.

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call my_procedure(?,?)}");  
int i = 0;
cs.setString(++i, advisor);
cs.setString(++i, adviceXml);

boolean isRs = cs.execute();
int updateCount = cs.getUpdateCount();
// cs.getUpdateCount() will return -1 if the current result is a ResultSet object 
// or there are no more results
// cs.getMoreResults() will return true  if the next result is a ResultSet object; 
// false if it is an update count or there are no more results

while (!isRs && (cs.getUpdateCount() != -1)) {
    isRs = cs.getMoreResults(); 
}

if (isRs) {
    ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
             groupId = rs.getString("psrg_idi");
        }
    } finally {
        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql).

First, you should decide if your SP will return a ResultSet or not. I mean, when you catch an error, you do `RETURN -1`. But, if all works fine, you perform a `SELECT`, which returns a ResultSet.

Said that, if you choose to return a value, you have to do:

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{? = call my_procedure (?,?)}");                
int i = 0;
cs.registerOutParameter(++i, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cs.setString(++i, advisor);
cs.setString(++i, adviceXml);

cs.execute();
int groupId = cs.getInt(1);
```

But, if you return a ResultSet, you have to do:

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call my_procedure (?,?)}");                
int i = 0;
cs.setString(++i, advisor);
cs.setString(++i, adviceXml);

ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
if (rs.next())
    int groupId = rs.getInt(1);
```

I've tested both methods using a toy SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure @v1 int, @v2 int 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --SELECT @v1 + @v2 as sumVal -- Comment this and uncomment previous line to test Return
RETURN @v1+@v2 -- Comment this and uncomment previous line to test ResultSet
END
```

Comment: Question is that how execute function return values ??

Comment: @neutrino, this is of no use... I am trying the same way as of the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1948518/674476

Comment: But, in your Stored procedure, you only do a `return -1` when catching errors, you don't return anything if all works fine.

Comment: @Imran Where have I said that cs.execute(); should return a value? Is that the reason for the down vote? What I say is that you should call cs.execute(); not cs.executeUpdate(); when calling to the SP.

Comment: this "select @psrg_idi as psrg_idi" statement is returning the value. In case of any exception, it will return -1

Comment: I think it doesn't. From the docs, there are two ways of returning values: RETURN and OUTPUT parameters. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx). Have you tried with `RETURN @psrg_idi` just before `END TRY`?

Comment: We can return this way as well. I am getting this value in the Delphi in the following way successfully: groupID:= StoredProc.Fields.FieldByName('psrg_idi').AsString;

Comment: But that's what I'm saying! In Delphi, you're accessing the result of calling the SP as a Resultset. If you want to do the same in Java, you have to call `executeQuery`.

Comment: But when I call executeQuery(), it show me exception like "the statement does not return a result set"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42139/discussion-between-neutrino-and-muhammad-ijaz)