# Unable to retrieve Stored Procedure Return value through Java

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jpa

I'm trying to retrieve results from stored procedures written in sql server 2008 through JPA. I've come across a very absurd situation in which I am able to retrieve results from stored procedures that have a select statement at the end. In this case, I'm able to retrieve the results by calling

> storedProcedureQuery.getSingleResult();

However, if the stored procedure contains a return statement at the end returning a value, I'm unable to get any result and the same query returns a null pointer exception.

The stored procedure which returns a value looks like:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE callSP
    @value int
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select 1;
END
GO
```

The stored procedures which causes an error looks like the one below:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE callSP
    @value int
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RETURN 1;
END
GO
```

Is there some other way in which return values can be retrieved through JPA?

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268187/retrieve-the-returned-value-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-java

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql

Comment: Thank you for the links, they seem to solve my problem, though they seem rather crude. Is there some way I can retrieve the return value using JPA itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to return a value, you have to do:

```
CallableStatement storedProcedureQuery = con.prepareCall("{? = call my_procedure (?,?)}"); 

storedProcedureQuery.execute();
int groupId = cs.getInt(1);`
```

But, if you return a ResultSet, you have to do:

```
ResultSet rs = storedProcedureQuery.executeQuery();
if (rs.next())
    int groupId = rs.getInt(1);
```