# Use the output parameter of an insert query as input parameter for another insert query in the same stored procedure in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure which inserts a new order in the NewOrder table and also updates the OrderedProduct table with the new information of the order. I am using `@@IDENTITY` to get the OrderID for OrderedProduct table.

```
    create proc sp_insert_new_order(
                                    @oValue float,
                                    @newID int OUTPUT,
                                    @productID int,
                                    @price float,
                                    @qty int)
   as
   begin
   insert into NewOrder values(GETDATE(),@oValue)
   set @newID = @@IDENTITY
   insert into OrderedProduct values(@productID,@newID,@qty,@price)
   end
```

My question is how i will make the call of this stored procedure from java?
This is what i tried so far

```
 public static void addNewOrderToDB(ArrayList<Product> list){
        Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement statement = null;
        float orderValue = 0;
        //calculate orderValue

        for(Product p : list){
            orderValue = orderValue + (p.getPrice() * p.getQty());              
        }
        System.out.println(orderValue);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            statement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = CALL sp_insert_new_order(?,?,?,?)}");
            statement.setFloat(3, orderValue);
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            //statement.execute();

            int uniqueID = statement.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(uniqueID);
            for(Product p : list){
                statement.setInt(1, p.getProductId());
                statement.setInt(2,uniqueID);
                statement.setInt(3, p.getQty());
                statement.setFloat(4, p.getPrice());
            }               
            statement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally{
            if(statement != null){
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if(connection != null){
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }           

        }
 }
```

Is there any other way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ add the identity as a return value for you proc :

```
create proc sp_insert_new_order(@oValue float,
                                @newID int,
                                @productID int,
                                @price float,
                                @qty int)
as
begin
insert into NewOrder values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@oValue)
select @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into OrderedProduct values(@productID,@newID,@qty,@price)

return @newID
end
```

2/ and then :
[Getting the Return Value from JDBC MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql)

**EDIT**

Or you can use as you wanted, the output parameter :

```
create proc sp_insert_new_order(@oValue float,
                                @newID int OUTPUT,
                                @productID int,
                                @price float,
                                @qty int)
as
begin
insert into NewOrder values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@oValue)
select @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into OrderedProduct values(@productID,@newID,@qty,@price)

end
```

and in your code, use the registerOutParameter method : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378596.aspx

Comment: Following your suggestions, to get the id for my new order i should execute the 2 queries separately.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the output parameter. I'll edit the answer

Comment: to use the `statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);` i have to call `statement.execute();` to can use the output parameter like this: `int uniqueID = statement.getInt(1);
                    for(Product p : list){
              statement.setInt(1, p.getProductId());
              statement.setInt(2,uniqueID);
              statement.setInt(3, p.getQty());
              statement.setFloat(4, p.getPrice());
             }   ` or at least this is what i've got from your suggestions

Comment: To get back the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value you need to execute the query first, yes (if I understood what you asked). Then you do a `getInt()` to get the value back.