# SP not returning resultset

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure which should return a code. PFB the sample SP.

```
USE [TEST]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_sp]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id int,
    @name varchar(25), 
    @return_code int    OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    select @return_code=1
    return @return_code
END
```

Java class where this SP is being called:

```
public int callSP() {

        Connection con = getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CallableStatement ct = null;
        int returnCode = -1;
        try {
            ct = con.prepareCall("{call test_sp (?,?,?)}");
            ct.setInt(1, 1);
            ct.setString(2, "divya");
            ct.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

            ct.executeQuery();

            returnCode = ct.getInt(3);

            if (returnCode == 0) {
                System.out.println("Success");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            database.close(rs, ct, con);
        }
        return returnCode;
    }
```

I am getting an exception while running this. The exception occurs on `ct.executeQuery();` and says that,

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try setting NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of your SP: `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Comment: Tried that. Still same issue.

Comment: There is no resultset in this SP.

Comment: Maybe try `ct.execute();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql

Comment: You should get rid of the RETURN in your procedure. The RETURN statement returns an integer which is designed to be used as a status of the execution, not a value. And you already have the value available in your output parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the return parameter as the scalar result of the call, like this :

```
    ct = con.prepareCall("{? = call test_sp (?,?)}");
    ct.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    ct.setInt(2, 1);
    ct.setString(3, "divya");
    ct.execute();

    returnCode = ct.getInt(1);
```

Some related topics here :

[Getting the Return Value from JDBC MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql)

[How to call scalar function from JDBC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/66d68cf8-3e1f-4854-a723-59842c160154/solved-how-to-call-scalar-function-from-jdbc?forum=sqldataaccess)