# Java - How to get ReturnCode from MySQL procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this stored procedure in MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure spResetPassword (IN in_email VARCHAR (50))
Begin
 Declare UserId int;
 Declare GUID varchar(64);

 Select UserId = nrIdentifikues
 from punetori
 where Email = in_email;

if UserId IS NOT NULL then
    Set GUID = UUID();

    Insert into tblResetPasswordRequests (ID, UserID, ResetRequestDateTime) Values(GUID, UserId, NOW());

    Select 1 as ReturnCode, GUID as UniqueId, in_email as Email;
else
    SELECT 0 as ReturnCode, NULL as UniqueId, NULL as Email;
end if;
end; //
DELIMITER ;
```

And code from java :

```
Connection con = DB.Connect2DB("semp");

try {
    CallableStatement sm = con.prepareCall("{call spResetPassword(?)}");
    sm.setString(1, txtEmail.getText());
    sm.execute();

    res = sm.getResultSet();
    int rCode = res.getInt("ReturnCode");
    while (res.next()) {
        if (rCode == 1) {
            SendPasswordResetEmail(res.getString("Email"), res.getString("GUID"));
            pnRequestReset.setVisible(false);
            con.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2.toString());
}
```

The problem is that `ReturnCode` is not a column, therefore `res.getInt("ReturnCode");` won't work. How can I access that variable? This worked perfectly fine in C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql#1948518

Comment: you want to return one parameter ?

Comment: So my code should look like:
sm.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER); 
sm.execute(); 
int returnValue = sm.getInt(1); 

and then ask if(returnValue==1), right?@Reimeus

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, it's either 1 (successful, data exists in table) or 0.

Comment: then why you use `res = sm.getResultSet();
                int rCode = res.getInt("ReturnCode");
                while(res.next())
                {
                    if (rCode==1)
                    {
                        SendPasswordResetEmail(res.getString("Email"), res.getString("GUID"));
                        pnRequestReset.setVisible(false);
                        con.close();
                    }
                }` ?

Comment: @YCF_L If the user exists on table, procedure will return '1' and if this return code (rCode) is 1, then I get to do some code (doesnt matter what's inside of if statement). The question was on how to access that return code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
CallableStatement sm = connection.prepareCall("{? = call spResetPassword(?)}");
//this is the return value----------------------^
sm .registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
sm .execute();
int code = sm .getInt(1);
```

so if your function return something you have to use :

```
{? = call name_function(?, ?)}
                        ^--^---------parameters of your function
 ^-----------------------------------return value of your function
```

---

either your function is not define correctly, it not return any thing, it should look like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spResetPassword (
IN in_email VARCHAR (50)
OUT code INT(1) -- <<--------------note this is how your procedure should return values
)
...
```

Comment: It's throwing this exception: Can't set IN parameter for return value of stored function call

Comment: yes @Arti because your function is not correct it not return any thing

Comment: Pardon me because I had to migrate from C#-SQL Server to Java - MySQL which im not familiar with. So the problem is in the stored procedure.. I should make it Return 1 instead of Select 1 as returncode?