# Get the SELECT result from a stored procedure in JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to run a stored procedure that runs a `SELECT` statement that results in a single column saying YES or NO. But I could not find a way to get this result in java.

My code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_verify_solutuion")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("cod_company", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("cod_person", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("result", Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
sp.setParameter("cod_company", 552);
sp.setParameter("cod_person", cod_person);

sp.execute();
//here I want to save the result in a String variable
```

I have tried with Void.class, ParameterMode.OUT (in the third parameter), but no success.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Return Value from JDBC MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql)

Comment: @Tanner Sorry, I  have changed the question now because I am not using pure JDBC, I am using JPA, so I don't use prepareCall like some solutions I've seen

Comment: `sp.getResultList` is what is used to get a ResultSet (and no OUT parameter). Since you don't post the stored proc then not much else to say

Answer (score 0):

Change the last parameter to be your `OUT` parameter, like you said

```
StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_verify_solutuion")
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("cod_company", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("cod_person", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("result", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
                sp.setParameter("cod_company", 552);
                sp.setParameter("cod_person", cod_person);

                sp.execute();
```

And then call the `getOutputParameterValue` method to store the result

```
String res = (String)sp.getOutputParameterValue("result");
```

Comment: It gives an error saying that I have too much parameters for the procedure. This procedure has only two input parameters and no output parameters in his specification, just a select statement (and some other configurations being done before this select)

Comment: @Mucida try putting the REF_CURSOR parameter first.

Comment: With REF_CURSOR (as first parameter or last) it gives an error saying that is a invalid JDBC data type. I have tried with Class.class and Void.class and String.class