# calling Stored Procedure in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[auth_user]
    @username nchar(50),
    @password nchar(50)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @response AS bit = 0;

    UPDATE dbo.Users
    SET @response = 1
    WHERE Username = @username
        AND Password = @password

    RETURN @response
END
```

I try to get return value from SP in Java

```
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement storedProcedure = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

       ...

    connection = Shop.OpenConnection();
    
    storedProcedure = connection.prepareCall("{call auth_user(?, ?)}");
    storedProcedure.setString(1, UsernameField.getText());
    storedProcedure.setString(2, PasswordField.getText());
    
    resultSet = storedProcedure.executeQuery(); //Error
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct username and password");
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password");
    }
```

I need to get return value(0 or 1), but I get error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend using an output parameter over the `RETURN` value, which is meant to denote the success of a procedure (`0` for success, `1` for failure). Your code also strongly implies you are storing plain text passwords; I hope not, as that is a *severe" vulnerability for both you and your users.

Comment: you can't use executeQuery if you don't return resultsets. You should use execute. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql

Comment: Also `nchar(50)`? So all your usernames and passwords are all _exactly_ 50 characters?

Answer (score 0):

I did it and I want to share with you this information.

```
connection = Shop.OpenConnection();

storedProcedure = connection.prepareCall("**{? = call auth_user(?, ?)}**");
storedProcedure.setString(2, UsernameField.getText());
storedProcedure.setString(3, PasswordField.getText());
        
storedProcedure.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
storedProcedure.execute();
        
System.out.println(storedProcedure.getInt(1));
```

I changed string of call SP -> **{? = call auth_user(?, ?)}**
and declared each parameter with its number. That is, the return value is 1, the passed parameter is 2, and the passed parameter is 3

Answer (score -1):

In your SP, you declare @response as bit but don't give it a default value. Bits can be 0, 1, or NULL. @response is set to NULL.

In the update, you set it to 1 only when username and password match. If they don't match, @response is still NULL.

This should fix it.

```
DECLARE @response AS bit = 0;
```

Comment: This changes nothing other than stopping a warning message being returned, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks).

Comment: But that is exactly what he is asking for. "I need to get return value(0 or 1), but I get error:"

Comment: Did you read the error..? This doesn't address that no result set is returned, nor (as I stated) changes the behaviour.